# Set different environment for same function in Lua 5.1

Tags: lua, luajit, lua-5.1

I would like to set different environments on the same function in Lua **5.1** (luajit):

```
f = function() print(a) end
b = setfenv(f, { a = 1, print = print })
c = setfenv(f, { a = 2, print = print })
```

I would like `b()` and `c()` to print different numbers

I've hacked a way by creating new function chunks based on `string.dump` and binds env to it, but is there a better more elegant way ? Alternatively, can a function somehow have different upvalues depending on some condition ?

```
function bind_env(f, env)
  return setfenv(loadstring(string.dump(f)), env)
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Change environment before every call: `b = function(...) return setfenv(f, b_env_table)(...) end`.  Maybe, it would be fast enough ;-)

Comment: Cool, a better hack than recompiling chunks :) I initially thought it wouldn't work with coroutines, but I just need to set the env before resume and reset it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A function's upvalues are determined by its lexical scope:

```
function test(a, b)
   function func(x) -- sees x, a and b
       print(a*x+b)
   end
   return func
end

f12 = test(1, 2) -- x+2
f23 = test(2, 3) -- 2x+3

f12(4)
f23(4)
```

The last two lines print 6 and 11. Technically, `test(a,b)` returns a different function object for every a, b, but notionally, it returns different closures of the same function (same sequence of bytecodes). So if you had

```
function func(a)
    return function() print(a) end
end
```

you could define a different closure for every a:

```
b = func(1) -- a=1
c = func(2) -- a=2
```

However note that `b==c` is false, but that's probably a good thing.